# How to use BodyPosition to move part smoothly in a line?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm creating a plane that flies through the air in a straight line. When I used BodyPosition, Roblox just flings the part instead of moving it in a line smoothly.

```lua
local bp = Instance.new("BodyPosition")
bp.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)
bp.Position = Vector3.new(856.13, 190.19, -3211.87)
bp.P = 100
bp.Parent = script.Parent
```

the start location of the part is 856.13, 190.19, 2237.94922

Comment: I think that the issue is in the size of the MaxForce vector.

Either that, or you'll have to use one of the other available body movers.

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/BodyPosition

Take a look at BODY MOVERS at the left side in the menu, those are the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BodyVelocity and then disabling it when the plane reaches the target